# Next to on the map

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

[image]

Is it wrong if we say block 1 is next to block 2 on this map? (When we are just focusing on the blocks?)

I know that next to is used when there is only little space between two things but here as it is on the map and the space is not that much to be considered can we simply say to someone who is looking at the map and can't find block 1 that it is next to block 2?

Comment: When you say that something is 'next to' another thing or place, the distance is _relatively_ small. Bath is 17 miles from Bristol, but they are next to each other when you look at a map of, or consider, the whole of Britain.

Comment: I add that if you told me something was next to something else on the map, I would assume the map was wrong -- they are next to each other on the map but not in reality.  I would, "They are next to each other according to the map" or "The map shows they are next to each other."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can say that.  I might be a little more clear to say "It is to the left of block two," since there are also blocks to the right and above and below.  But in practice, many people would just say "next to."

The only problem with your quoted question is some lack of punctuation, and a preference for spelled out words in a sentence.  Perhaps more like:

"I know that 'next to' is used when there is only little space between two things, but as it is on the map the space is not that much. Can we simply say to someone who is looking at the map, and who can't find block one, that it is next to block two?"

Answer (score 0):

While "next to" would probably be understood by most people, I think the most common phrasing when talking about city blocks on a map would be "one block over"

Comment: So it isn't wrong to say next to. Am I right?

Comment: It's not grammatically wrong, no. And most people would understand you just fine.

Comment: As a British English speaker, I would definitely say _next to_ rather than _one block over_.